# Why is this question's content cut off?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160376/why-move-your-javascript-files-to-a-different-main-domain-that-you-also-own) where the content suddenly stops:

[image: cut-off question]

At first I looked at the history; it looks fine. Then I opened the editor and lo and behold:

[image: not cut-off preview]

The preview is rendered fine. It's not a render bug, the HTML accurately reflects what is shown here. It also shouldn't be something session related. It happened in my normal session in Chrome but also in a private window in Firefox.

What is going on here? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 5):

Old bug.

A long time ago, there was a markdown => HTML bug that caused some long posts to get cut. That is the rendered HTML was cut and stored in the DB.

The bug was fixed, but some posts were never updated to re-render the HTML - this is one such post (see the edit date on that sucker - coincides with the time that bug was in effect).

Anywho - I removed an empty line there, all is well now.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I wasn't aware that the rendered HTML is saved in the database. So it seems anybody can fix these issues by simply making a small edit.

Comment: @musiKk - yes, that's absolutely the case.